# Unable to record web application using load runner

Tags: loadrunner

I am using load runner 12.5. I am having trouble recording web application using IE and chrome. When I go to the site directly without load runner, I can access just fine.

advanced settings… > Change proxy settings… > LAN Settings and deselected "Use a proxy server for your LAN".

While recording, I selected Web HTTP protocol. I get the below message after it goes to the web url:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> example.com took too long to respond. Try: Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall Running Windows Network
> Diagnostics ERR_TIMED_OUT ReloadHIDE DETAILS Check your Internet
> connection Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems, or other
> network devices you may be using. Allow Chrome to access the network
> in your firewall or antivirus settings. If it is already listed as a
> program allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list
> and adding it again.
>
> If you use a proxy server… Check your proxy
> settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy
> server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy
> server: Go to the Chrome menu > Settings >  Show advanced settings… >
> Change proxy settings… > LAN Settings and deselect "Use a proxy server
> for your LAN".

Answer (score 0):

- Is this a local application inside of your organization?
- Can you hit any other applications for recording or just this one?  An example, can you connect to the sample Tours site which is typically a local installation?
- Are you recording in sockets or proxy mode?

Comment: Public facing site. Tried with or without proxy in load runner, Tried socket or winnet level, tried HTML and URL based. It simply tries to open the URL and then I get this error. Above error message from chrome. If I run it in IE, i get blank screen for a long time... Web HTTP protocol.

Comment: Try a different website, this one inside of your enterprise.  Ideally, use the training website, HP Tours, installed locally, as a control element in your troubleshooting.   Understanding whether it works all on one host can hekp to identify issues within the host or external to the host for troubleshooting

Comment: I will. Is there any checklist of configurations I should go thru before I record a web application using web http protocol? I am getting mix answers on this issue. So, first I would like to confirm any config settings that I must have before recording.

Comment: The defaults should be fine except in edge conditions.   Given your moniker, I can also confirm LoadRunner works just fine with Drupal sites on versions 6x-8x with defaults socket based recording as we use Drupal for our infrastructure.

Comment: Script was generated fine with web tour app. Problem happens with any other public sites. I even tried to access yahoo, msn. I get message """Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.msn.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID............."""

Comment: That is a browser warning common when Proxies are in the middle.  Are you recording in Proxy mode?   

Also, please read the license agreement regarding the use of LoadRunner (and performance testing tools in general) against any public website where you do not have the explicit written permission from those who own, manage, control the site.  Most public sites also have license restrictions on using automation on their site.  Otherwise its like driving around and using a nuclear bazooka on someone's mailbox

Comment: Under advance tab, if i select "use proxy", i get error "Your connection is not private...." If I uncheck "use proxy", I get error "This site can’t be reached

example.com took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_TIMED_OUT

Comment: What is your level of training & mentoring with this tool?

Comment: If it works recording local, but not remote then the issue is remote to your box, or deals with remote connections from your box.

Comment: Your next step is to record against something inside your enterprise, behind your proxy to the internet, to see if you can hit at other web host internally

Answer (score 0):

This gem of knowledge worked for me:
Run VuGen as administrator each time an Edge recording is performed. When you select Microsoft Edge as the web browser, VuGen enables the loopback calls.